# How to redirect without waitng for full page load

Tags: html, redirect, web

I'm owner of PTP website (with tons of ads :) and I want to redirect to another website without waiting for page load. Any code or something?

My current code:

```
//tons of ads
//and:
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com" />
```

Comment: Try put the meta on the top of page…

Answer (score 0):

Right at the beginning of your code add:

```
<?
header('Location: http://example.com');
?>
```

Comment: Add **die;** after **header(...);**.